# How to programmatically open and bind text of an onscreen keyboard to a textbox when a textbox is tapped inside a UWP ListView?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

Trying to show custom keyboard controls when a textbox is tapped inside a listview. I am unable to a to show the correct keyboard and then the keystrokes won't be unique to that text box but instead it appear in all of the boxes with that property. Each keyboard 'Text' property is bond to a GuestItem property. How to bind each keyboard control to the correct guest item property inside each row in the listView?

**GuestNameControl.xaml.cs**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollerView" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource KioskCartTotalBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,2,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,-34" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="True" IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="False" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="True" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GuestNames, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="GuestListItemsControl" IsEnabled="True" IsTapEnabled="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemsControlStretchedItemContainerStyle}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"></ItemsWrapGrid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:GuestNameItemControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <controls:NameKeyboard x:Name="FirstNameKeyboard" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.GuestNameItemViewModel.IsFirstNameBlockSelected, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="452" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <controls:NameKeyboard x:Name="LastNameKeyboard" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.GuestNameItemViewModel.IsLastNameBlockSelected, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="452" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <controls:NumericKeyboard x:Name="DOBKeyboard" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.GuestNameItemViewModel.IsDOBBlockSelected, Mode=OneWay}" Text="{Binding DOB, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="452" Opacity="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

**GuestNameItemControl.xaml**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding TicketName}" Style="{StaticResource TicketNameBoxStyle}" />
    <!--First Name-->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="First Name" Style="{StaticResource KioskTextBoxLabelStyle}" />
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" IsTapEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource KioskTextBoxBorderStyle}" Height="64">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBox x:Name="FirstNameTextBox" 
                     IsTapEnabled="True"                                        
                     IsEnabled="True"                                      
                     Tag="{Binding TextBlockId}" 
                     Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     Style="{StaticResource KioskTextEntryTextBoxStyle}" 
                     TextAlignment="Left" 
                     TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                     Width="310"                                                     
                     MaxLength="30" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <!--Last Name-->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Last Name" Style="{StaticResource KioskTextBoxLabelStyle}" />
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="LastNameTextBlockBorder" IsTapEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource KioskTextBoxBorderStyle}" Height="64">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBox x:Name="LastNameTextBox" 
                     Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     Style="{StaticResource KioskTextEntryTextBoxStyle}" 
                     TextAlignment="Left" 
                     TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                     Width="310" 
                     MaxLength="30" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <!--Date of Birth-->
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Date of Birth" Style="{StaticResource KioskTextBoxLabelStyle}" />
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="DOBTextBlockBorder" IsTapEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource KioskTextBoxBorderStyle}" Height="64">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBox x:Name="DOBTextBox" 
                     Text="{Binding DOB, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     Style="{StaticResource KioskTextEntryTextBoxStyle}" 
                     TextAlignment="Left" 
                     TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                     Width="310" 
                     MaxLength="20" 
                     extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask="99\\99\\9999" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

**GuestNameItemControl.xaml.cs**

```
    public GuestNameItemControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        FirstNameTextBox.GettingFocus += OnTextBoxGettingFocus;
        LastNameTextBox.GettingFocus += OnTextBoxGettingFocus;
        DOBTextBox.GettingFocus += OnTextBoxGettingFocus;                               
    }  

    GuestNameItemViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as GuestNameItemViewModel;                  

    private void OnTextBoxGettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;

        var datacontext = textBox.DataContext;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((datacontext as GuestNameItemViewModel).FirstName);
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should listen `TextBox` GettingFocus event. And it will trigger when TextBox turn into typing state. You could get current `TextBox` datacontext and pass it to screen keyboard.

For example

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Id" Text="{Binding ID}" />
                <TextBox
                    x:Name="FirstName"
                    GettingFocus="FirstName_GettingFocus"
                    Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="LastName" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void FirstName_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    var textbox  = sender as TextBox;
    var datacontext = textbox.DataContext;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((datacontext as Person).ID);

    /*process this datacontext in your screen keyboard out put method */
}
```

**Update**

You could bind current datacontext to your screen keyboard. I will use TextBox to replace your screen keyboard to make sample.

```
<TextBox x:Name="NameInput" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />



private void FirstName_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    var datacontext = textbox.DataContext;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((datacontext as Person).ID);

   /*bind datacontext with your screen keyboard  text property*/
    var binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = datacontext;
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("FirstName");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    NameInput.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);

}
```

Please don't forget implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your model class for example

```
private string _firstName;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        _firstName = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How to pass the datacontext to the keyboard control? I do not have a keyboard output method. the keyboard control is just a UIElement that bind the keystrokes to the specified property.

Comment: I made some changes to my code original code. I broke the listview and the items to separate controls. the keyboards controls are in the GuestNameControl.xaml and the dynamic textboxes are in the GuestNameItemControl.xaml I do not have access to my keyboard controls from GuestNameItemControl.xaml

Comment: I have updated the reply, please refer to the update part.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. still no luck. NameInput.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding); throws a memory corrupt error.

Comment: Can you share the code you have written ?

Comment: Hey I got it to work by adding a unique tag to each textbox and I used the GotFocus event to bring up the keyboard and assign the selected textbox. Then in the keyboard UserControl, I added a few invokes so I can access the keydown and backspace events and that is how I got it to work.

Comment: It looks you have found the solution, please go ahead post your answer below.